# a capitalization question on the sentence ''second world war...''

Tags: capitalization

In the sentence (just a sentence to be provided an example, I made it up) ''I think the second World War was more devastating than World War I'' so I checked capitalization rules on [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/capitalization-rules/) and I didn't find any reason to capitalize ''s'' of ''second''. However, the application (grammarly) itself finds no mistake when I capitalize ''s'' of ''second'' Is there a grammar rule that regulates this ? Thank you.

Comment: Rule 8: Specific periods, eras, and historical events that have proper names should be capitalized. *Second* is a part of the proper name as *World* or *War* is. Similarly, we say "World War One"

Comment: Yes to what @AndrewTobilko said. You could also write, "I think the second world war was more devastating than the first" (although people usually use proper nouns to refer to those wars).

Comment: Don't say thanks in the question, it only increases noise. See: [Expected Behavior](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically we consider the name of the war to be "Second World War".  The word "Second" is part of the name, and so is capitalised as a proper noun.